# Can i have multiple saves on borderlands 2 on the same character? (ps3)

Tags: borderlands-2

I just completed borderlands 2, but I want to restart for True Vault Hunter mode. Will I lose my first playthrough?, Or can I transfer it to another PSN account and do TVHM on my main account without losing anything?.

Answer (score 1):

At least on the PC the TVHM doesn't wipe your previous play through completely.  When you choose a character it will let you choose which mode to play the game in so you could go back to playing pre-TVHM again.  One thing that made me not want to go back was that my challenges carried over.  Since I wasn't starting the Challenges over I was happy to keep plugging forward.  You get to keep your Eridium and bank inventory too so it doesn't feel like you're starting over.